# Changing individual elements of a matrix in Tikz

Tags: matrices, tikz-graphs, changes

I am preparing lecture notes and I need to manipulate a matrix between iteration. Typically, only few elements change. Therefore, it would be nice to change these elements instead of copying a matrix again, and again. I would be grateful for your insights.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit,automata}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix(rij) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex}]
{
 6      &  11    &   5    & 0  \\
 4      &   3    &   3    & M  \\
 3      &   6    &   7    & 0  \\
 3      &   7    &   8    & M  \\
 M      &   0    &   0    & 0  \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is very easy to manipulate matrix elements. But I do not understand the question. (1) which "iteration" are you referring to in "I need to manipulate a matrix between iteration"? (2) What should be changed to what?

Comment: For instance, I would like to the add a 2 to the element in the first line and second column (1,2) and it would read 13 instead of 11.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: draw the matrix in a pic, and then set the value by some key `value to be changed`. The benifit is that you can access the coordinate of the matrix as usual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit,automata,positioning}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\tikzset{
  value to be changed/.store in=\anytl,
  value to be changed=11, % default value,
  mymatrix/.pic={
    \matrix(-rij) [
      matrix of math nodes,
      nodes in empty cells,
      nodes={
        minimum size=1cm,
        outer sep=0pt,
        text height=1.5ex,
        text depth=.25ex
      },
      ampersand replacement=\&
    ]
    {
     6      \&  \anytl\&   5    \& 0  \\
     4      \&   3    \&   3    \& M  \\
     3      \&   6    \&   7    \& 0  \\
     3      \&   7    \&   8    \& M  \\
     M      \&   0    \&   0    \& 0  \\
    };
    \coordinate (-south) at (current bounding box.south);
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic (a) at (0, 0) {mymatrix};
  \pic [value to be changed=change, below=of a-south] {mymatrix};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! That is works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can perform operations on the entries of the matrix, with may depend on the counts `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow` and `\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn`. The matrix content are stored in `\myarray`. If you just say

```
\mymatrix
```

you will get the corresponding matrix, but if you say e.g.

```
\mymatrix[\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=2
\pgfmathparse{int(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow+\originalentry)}\pgfmathresult
\else
\originalentry
\fi]
```

you will add the row index to the entries of the second column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\edef\myarray{{"6","11","5","0"},%
{"4","3","3","M"},%
{"3","6","7","0"},%
{"3","7","8","M"},%
{"M","0","0","0"}}
\newcommand\mymatrix[1][\originalentry]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(rij) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, 
nodes={minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex},
cells={nodes={execute at begin node={\pgfmathsetmacro\originalentry{{\myarray}[\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1][\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1]}%
#1}}},
ampersand replacement=\&]
{
 \& \& \& \\
 \& \& \& \\
 \& \& \& \\
 \& \& \& \\
 \& \& \& \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\mymatrix
\bigskip

\mymatrix[\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=2
\pgfmathparse{int(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow+\originalentry)}\pgfmathresult
\else
\originalentry
\fi]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is almost what I need to do. But I would rather see the results instead, for stance 12 and not 1+11